# Promise not being called due to previous Promise being resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nodemailer

```
  Node: v4.3.1
  NodeMailer: 2.4.1
  Operating system: windows 10
```

I'm using NodeMailer to send an email to the specified address. I'm using the sendMail function, and I'm not getting the callback so I can never determine the error being thrown, if one is even being thrown.

The callback is not being called here:
https://gist.github.com/KieronWiltshire/a86ad6e9ba7c084f80eb855604d92e39#file-callbacknotbeingcalled-js-L40

The options are being loaded, here are the options:
https://gist.github.com/KieronWiltshire/3f7fd75b31c689a84f6370efe06551c9

Here is the log to console:
https://gist.github.com/KieronWiltshire/fea16bd097098b6f3a11019d67c237c6

**Update (26/05/2016):**

https://github.com/KieronWiltshire/dracade-backend/blob/develop/api/user.js#L119

It appears that resolving the promise of where the event is being triggered from is preventing the email from being sent!

Comment: where are you calling mailer ?

Comment: @realseanp https://gist.github.com/KieronWiltshire/a86ad6e9ba7c084f80eb855604d92e39#file-callbacknotbeingcalled-js-L21

Comment: no where are you executing the function ? that is where you are defining it

Comment: @realseanp my apologies, here: https://gist.github.com/KieronWiltshire/69bd1876763470063dceb92887403136

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm such an idiot. The issue is that mocha is moving onto the next test before the event listener has finished processing. Running the code in a production environment works perfectly fine.